# PluginMissingError due to vertical_demo in OpenEdx

Tags: python, openedx

I want to install xblock sdk and followed this tutorial

[Xblock installation](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/xblock-tutorial/en/latest/getting_started/create_first_xblock.html)

But, now I am facing **PluginMissingError** due to **vertical_demo**. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring the cause of this problem, I have came to discussion and found the solution on Google groups that solves my problem. Here is the link:
[xblock pluginmissingerror](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/edx-code/PAru0A1k3No/IfFXAu80AQAJ)

It says that you need to run **make install** command in xblock-sdk directory.

Comment: Than you, it works. Also if you have issues with running on python3, apply changes from that commit https://github.com/ffedoroff/xblock-sdk/commit/d6bae00bde20be85646fb7dcb359d32d4f81fb99